# remove misconfiguration in pytorch lightning trainer

Tags: python, pytorch

I defined a  model and then I have tried to fit the model on my dataset in pytrorch. it gives the below error. please clarify how to solve that

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'float'

```
class PneumoniaModel(pl.LightningModule):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
        self.model.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size = (7,7), stride = (2,2), padding =(3,3), bias=False)
        self.model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(in_features = 512, out_features = 1, bias = True)

        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr = 1e-4)
        self.loss_fn = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight = torch.tensor([3]))

        self.train_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy(task='binary')
        self.val_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy(task='binary')

    def forward(self, data):
        pred = self.model(data)
        return pred
  
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x_ray, label = batch, batch_idx
        label = label.float()
        pred = self(x_ray)[:,0]
        loss = self.loss_fn(pred, label)

        self.log("Train_Loss", loss)
        self.log("Step Train ACC :", self.train_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred), label.int()))

        return loss

    def on_train_epoch_end(self):
        epoch_average = torch.stack(self.training_step()).mean()
        self.log("training_epoch_average", epoch_average)
        self.training_step.clear()  # free memory

    def validation_step_outputs(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x_ray, label = batch, batch_idx
        label = label.float()
        pred = self(x_ray)[:,0]
        loss = self.loss_fn(pred, label)

        self.log("Val Loss", loss)
        self.log("Step Val ACC :", self.val_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred), label.int()))

    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
        epoch_average = torch.stack(self.validation_step_outputs()).mean()
        self.log("validation_epoch_average", epoch_average)
        self.validation_step_outputs.clear()  # free memory


   def configure_optimizers(self):
       return [self.optimizer]
```

> 

it's for a PyTorch model for classification of x-ray images

Answer (score 0):

The model that is provided to the `Trainer.fit` method must be a `LightningModule`, which has the `training_step()`, `train_dataloader()` and `configure_optimizers()` defined. Without these methods, it is unclear for the Trainer how to optimizer the model (which optimizer and loss function to use, as well as how the data should be presented to the model).

Moreover, one could also define a `LightningDataModule` that defines how any dataloaders are constructed. Passing a train and validation dataloader to the `Trainer.fit()` method is then not necessary if both the model and the datamodule are passed to `Trainer.fit()`.

See [this tutorial from the Pytorch Lightning docs](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/model/train_model_basic.html) on how to define Pytorch Lightning models and see [this tutorial from the Pytorch Lightning docs](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/data/datamodule.html) on how to use Pytorch Lightning datamodules.

EDIT after question edit:
The `init` method of a class should begin and start with a double underscore to be treated as a special method. Otherwise, it will not be called when initializing instances. Moreover, the optimizer should be specified like in the tutorial behind the link above:

```py
class PneumoniaModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        self.lr = 1e-4
  
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.lr)    
        return optimizer
```

Comment: thank you. it was a problem with the version of python and pytorch which i solved. now the problem is below error. do u have any idea on how to deal with that?

Comment: AttributeError: 'PneumoniaModel' object has no attribute 'optimizer'

Comment: I do not know how your `PneumoniaModel` is defined and where/how `PneumoniaModel.optimizer` is used. Did you follow the model tutorial of pytorch lightning which I linked to in my answer? Or could you elaborate on how `PneumoniaModel` is defined?

Comment: I updated the question. you can see how i implemented model and what is error

Comment: I edited my original answer to reflect your edited question.

Comment: thank you. now it gives this error      AttributeError: 'PneumoniaModel' object has no attribute 'lr'

Comment: Did you add *double* underscores before and after `init` to make `init` a special method?

Comment: yes but after increasing underscore to two it gives this error                           AttributeError: cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call

Comment: When inheriting from pytorch (lightning) modules, one needs to call the parent `__init__` method with `super().__init__()`. For clarity, I added this to my answer. Not to be rude, but pasting that exact error message into a search engine would have helped you solve it by yourself.